# PHP => Alternative to session data?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

i have a Web Application where Cookies and Session are both important.

Since the Web Application is load balanced on different server, i am looking for suggestions to Alternative Store for the Session data that all server will be able to access.

Some sessions could live up to severals days.

The solutions that come to my mind:

- Native PHP Sessions (this is the one i want to stop using)
- MySQL Database
- Serialize and write to a file (i want to avoid this, for performances)
- Memcache (however it could become very big or older data getting knocked out)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question was closed as I was submitting an answer. Anyway... I suggest you continue using "Native PHP Sessions" but write a [custom session handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php). You can use any database you want...even the one you are likely already using with your persistent website data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a no sql database like Couchbase or Redis, it is similar to using Memcache however they both have hard-disk persistence whereas Memcache is just an in-memory cache and so you get the problem where old data can get dropped when Memcache runs to its limit.

Comment: Redis is a good idea. From my experience though, I'd stay away from Couchbase for this kind of thing, since it's not entirely reliable (under heavy stress, it will often return "not found" when the record is actually there). MongoDB is also a good candidate.

Comment: I use Redis, its pretty good and I like the fact TTL just works on the records so there's no messing about with clearup. Had a dabble with Couchbase, the whole GUI / browser setup interface thing annoyed me too much to bother much with it beyond that though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a database as an alternative. I have used it in the past and it has worked perfectly well for me. When it comes to choosing a database to do the task, I would go with one that is already part of the infrastructure and something I know. In other words, I do not really recommend using a NoSQL database if you are already not familiar with it. I have used MySQL and Oracle as session stores in the past and they have worked with zero hassle for me.

But then again if you are comfortable with NoSQLs, or want to learn them, you might go that direction. Bottom line - I would stick with a database I know as an alternate PHP Session Store.